# How can I see configured rules for a Azure Service Bus topic subscription on Mac (or online)?

Tags: macos, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I have a forwarding subscription already configured/defined in Azure Service Bus and it has a filter rule which I want to see but the Azure Portal doesn't show filter, it doesn't even show what is 'forwardTo' property of the subscription is. I am using Mac, how can I check these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a few several cross-platform options, some are free and some are paid.

- [Cerulean Azure Service Bus](https://www.cerebrata.com/products/cerulean/features/azure-service-bus/topics-and-subscriptions)
- [Serverless360](https://www.serverless360.com/)

Comment: Yes, there is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/servicebus?view=azure-cli-latest